# How to make a click counter update more than once when clicked?

Tags: php, mysql

I've currently Implemented a click counter if the value is set to null and you click on the link it will update to one. But when it's clicked for the second time it does not update it's stays as one.

```
public function getUpdateClick($Id) {
    $Id=DB::escape_string($Id);
    $i=1;
    $click=0;
    $click=$click+$i;

    $updatesArray=array('clicks'=>$click);// the column which is going to be updated

    $this->setTable('pages'); //setting the table name

    $where="id=$Id";

    $result=$this->update($updatesArray,$where); // query executed
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting `$click=0` when you add 1 immediately after?

Comment: Because you never use `$set="click=click+1";` but always `$click=0+1;`.

Comment: Becasue I kept getting an error message of unassigned variable

Comment: Right, but you could simply set `$click` to 1 since they seem to be static values (not passed by referenced)

Answer (score 0):

```
$click=0;
$click=$click+$i;
```

Remove first line and store the value of $click as session variable or store it in database.

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you should first check if there is a value for `clicks` on the `pages` tables for the specific page (`where id=$id`). If there isn't, then you can give `clicks=1`, otherwise get that value and add 1.

But here's how I'd do it: I'd edit the table by disabling ALLOW NULL in the `clicks` column, so that by default, when a new page is created, it's **default value is 0**. Then I'd use the code below:

```
public function getUpdateClick($Id){
    $Id=DB::escape_string($Id);

    //You can edit the 3 lines below to check the database 
    //  in pages table in clicks column where id=$Id in your custom way
    $fetching sql_result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM pages where id=$Id')
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetching sql_result);
    $current_number_of_clicks = $row['clicks'];

    $click= $current_number_of_clicks;
    $click=$click+1;

    $updatesArray=array('clicks'=>$click);// the column which is going to be updated

    $this->setTable('pages'); //setting the table name
    $set="click=click+1"; // column and value
    $where="id=$Id";  // 

    $result=$this->update($updatesArray,$where); // query executed
}
} // I assume this closes your class
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time the function is invoked the value of $click is set to 0 and then 1 in the next statement. If you want the value to persist, you should use an attribute in a table and increment it every time you click.